# HTML page, multiple refreshing "draw on canvas" from IPcamera snapshots

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

i'm setting up my home web page where i want to have live feed from my 7 cameras. For 6 of them i must use a refreshing jpeg, since all i can get is a snapshot of the current view or an rtsp feed. For the last one i use an `iframe` since i can get a constant refreshing web page.

So, this is the script that i use to refresh the snapshot

```
<script>
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawOnCanvas();
    setTimeout(timedRefresh, 100);
  }
  // set src AFTER assigning load
imageObj.src = "http://192.168.2.136/snap.jpeg?" + Math.random();

function timedRefresh() {
  imageObj.src = "http://192.168.2.136/snap.jpeg?" + Math.random();
  //drawOnCanvas(); //flicker remover
}

function drawOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
</script>
```

It works smoothly but when i add a second canvas, creating a new script afther the previous where i change the id to "canvasX" and the target IP to another camera

```
<script>
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawOnCanvas();
    setTimeout(timedRefresh, 100);
  }
  // set src AFTER assigning load
imageObj.src = "http://192.168.2.122/snap.jpeg?" + Math.random();

function timedRefresh() {
  imageObj.src = "http://192.168.2.122/snap.jpeg?" + Math.random();
  //drawOnCanvas(); //flicker remover
}

function drawOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
</script>
```

and i try to render both canvas using this code in the body section

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="1080" height="608"> </canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width="1080" height="608"> </canvas>
<canvas id="canvas3... etc
```

only the last canvas is rendered and all the others are simply not rendered.

All the feeds should be one on top of the other, so when i scroll (this is smartphone focused) i can see all the streams; this is why there is no spacing or else, due to the 1080x1920 of most of the home devices. I'm hosting on an apache server on a RaspberryPi 3.

Comment: Did you have twice defined methods like timedRefresh in your code. If yuo separete code with <script> tag they are still same namespace .Last canvas script overrides other. Looks like that...

Comment: Why do you use a canvas exactly? On your raspi, are you using motion? Why don't you use mhpeg streams instead of atill images?

Comment: @NikolaLukic Yes, i use timed refresh every time i open and close the script, simply beacause i need every image from diffrent IP to be refreshed. Is it a mistake?

Comment: @Kaiido I use canvas cause this is what i used in another project. I'm not using motion on the raspi. The cameras does not produce mjpeg streams but only snapshots.

Comment: These cameras usually have rtsp, so you can have a live stream. Check if your cameras have this option.available and maybe it will be easier for you to use it.

Comment: @FcoRodr They have it, but how do i put it in the html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda solved it. I created 6 diffrent html pages with only the canvas script in it, then i added 6 iframe pointing to each html page. Maybe it's not clean but it works. This way i need 5MB/second, it only works on LAN.